# convert task<string> to string

Tags: c#, async-await, win-universal-app

I want to parse from a JSON file in a universal windows phone application but I can't convert task to string

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        String responseLine;
        JObject o;
        try
        {
            string responseBodyAsText;

            HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost/list.php").Result;

            //response = await client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
           // responseLine = responseBodyAsText;
              string Website = "http://localhost/list.php";
            Task<string> datatask =  httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(string.Format(Website, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks)));
            string data = await datatask;
            o = JObject.Parse(data);
            Debug.WriteLine("firstname:" + o["id"][0]);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
        }
```

I have error in this line

```
 string data = await datatask;
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Would `string data = datatask.Result;` work?

Answer (score 14):

Looking into [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-task), you can get that using: Result property.

For Example:

```
    Task<int> task1 = myAsyncMethod(); //You can also use var instead of Task<int>
    int i = task1.Result;
```

Comment: Putting a blocking method such as `Task.Result` in a class constructor is not a great idea.

Comment: @Peregrine Why not?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `await` inside a constructor. You'll need to create an `async` method for that.

Generally I don't recommend using `async void`, but when you're calling it from the constructor it's somewhat justified.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.LoadContents();
}

private async void LoadContents()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    String responseLine;
    JObject o;
    try
    {
        string responseBodyAsText;

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost/list.php");

        //response = await client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       // responseLine = responseBodyAsText;
          string Website = "http://localhost/list.php";
        Task<string> datatask =  httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(string.Format(Website, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks)));
        string data = await datatask;
        o = JObject.Parse(data);
        Debug.WriteLine("firstname:" + o["id"][0]);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException hre)
    {
        // You might want to actually handle the exception
        // instead of silently swallowing it.
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this code but I get this error   
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @AlaEddineHelmiHaouala, inspect your `data` string under the debugger. Chances are you're dealing with malformed JSON (or non-JSON content).

Comment: thank's for your answer but when I called the async method to show a list of the my product it is not shown in the emulator but it is shown in the console.
what's the problem her ?

Comment: The good practice is to user Task as return type instead of Void. We should not use void from the Async method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```cs
Task<string> post = postPostAsync("Url", data).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
post.Result.ToString();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [answer] a question.  This question was asked over 4 years ago.

Comment: @GoodJuJu is it a problem to answer questions that are 4 years old or older? I am asking because I have answered quite a lot questions that are 8-9 years old myself, and I never got feedback that it's an inappropriate thing to do.